# Using every 2 ints of a string as variables for a method C

Tags: c

Say I have `char* b = "2 3, 32 3, 6 8, 9 10"` and a method `randMethod(int x, int y)`

How would i keep going through the string putting every 2 int as as inputs for randMethod(x, y)?

So it would end up being something like:

```
randMethod(2, 3);

randMethod(32, 3);

randMethod(6, 8);

randMethod(9, 10);
```

Comment: _sscanf_ and _strchr_ allow to do that easily, see answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like that :

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

void randMethod(int x, int y)
{
  printf("%d %d\n", x, y);
}

int main()
{
  const char * b = "2 3, 32 3, 6 8, 9 10";
  int x, y;

  while (sscanf(b, "%d %d", &x, &y) == 2) {
    randMethod(x, y);
    b = strchr(b, ',');
    if (b == NULL)
      break;
    b += 1;
  }

  return 0;
}
```

Compilation and execution :

```
pi@raspberrypi:/tmp $ gcc -pedantic -Wextra c.c
pi@raspberrypi:/tmp $ ./a.out
2 3
32 3
6 8
9 10
pi@raspberrypi:/tmp $
```